# Python command "os.system" not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, python-2.7

So, I tested os.system(call) with one .py file, where I put just notification, and it's work. 
But another file not working. Another file contains a lot of code, just show you from what that start:

```
import sys, socket, subprocess, time, os, platform, struct, getpass, datetime, plistlib, re, stat, grp, shutil
import string, json, traceback, pwd, urllib, urllib2, base64, binascii, hashlib, sqlite3, bz2, pickle, ast
import StringIO, zipfile, hmac, tempfile, ssl
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from glob import glob
```

How can I run that file?

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using `os.system` in the first place (you're already using `subprocess`, so you should know that). But meanwhile, just showing us 6 random and probably unrelated lines of code isn't a [mcve]. Show us how you try to call it, and what error you get.

Comment: Please add more details, you've posted imports only.

Comment: Also, why is this tagged both python-3.x and python-2.7? Which one are you using?

Comment: Please define "not working".  Did you get an error message?  How do you know it didn't run?  Did you test the return code from `os.system()`?

Comment: I tried all calls... os.system, subprocess etc. All time the same end

Comment: I use python-2.7

Comment: "not working" - just not do what that script have to do. Without errors. But when I run just that script from terminal - it is working.

Answer (score 3):

If that really is the start of your script, then your script cannot be executed. If you want to make a Python script executable on POSIX systems (including Mac OS X), you need a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line at the very start of the file. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

You also need to make sure the executable bit is set (`chmod u+x myscript.py`).

But all of this can be avoided if you just don't use `os.system`. You're already importing `subprocess`, so just use it:

```
subprocess.run([sys.executable, "myscript.py"])
```

This runs a copy of the same Python interpreter that's already running the calling script, and tells it to run your script.

(Of course you *can* do that with `os.system`, if you want to deal with string concatenation and possibly needing quoting, and if you want to spawn an extra shell for no reason, and if you want to make sure you have no control over the output…)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre How do you know I didn't create an object named `myscript` and save a pathname to some script in its `.py` attribute? :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I try to use it, always get error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run'`

Comment: @VladyslavPG This is why it’s important for you to tell us which version of Python you’re using, instead of tagging your question with every version. `run` isn’t there in 3.3 or 2.6, for example, so you’ll want to use `call` or `check_call` instead. See the docs for `subprocess` for your version and you can see what is available.